# Fill value in rows based on second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

```
create table a (
    name char(10),
    addr int,
    salary money
)    

create table b (
    name char(10),
    addr int,
    salary money
)

insert into a values ('kesh', '2', '10')
insert into a values ('bis', '11', '30')
insert into a values ('kir', '13', '30')
insert into a values ('sss', '14', '30')

insert into b values ('kesh', '3', null)
insert into b values ('bis', '12', null)
insert into b values ('sss', '14', '30')
insert into b values ('maa', '16', '1000')
```

I need this result from the above table. it would be great if someone help me with this.

```
name       addr newSalary
bis         11  30.00
bis         12  30.00
kesh        2   10.00
kesh        3   10.00
kir         13  30.00
maa         16  1000.00
sss         14  30.00
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO is about helping you, not doing it for you.

Comment: Seems a strange example, 2 people can easily have the same name. You really need a unique ID?

Comment: HI DAle I have done this and got the result but it seems quite long code                                                                           select distinct aa.name, aa.addr, coalesce(aa.salary,bb.salary)as newSalary
from
 (select * from a
 union
 select * from b)aa
left join
 (select * from a
 union
 select * from b) bb
on aa.name = bb.name
where coalesce(aa.salary,bb.salary) is not null

Comment: Please [edit] any additional information into the question.

Answer (score 0):

For this dataset, you could use `union all` and window functions:

```
select 
    name,
    addr,
    coalesce(salary, max(salary) over(partition by name)) new_salary
from (
    select name, addr, salary from a
    union all
    select name, addr, salary from b
) t
```

This somehow assumes that `name`s are unique in each table.

Comment: @user3784766: that's the same query without `union all`, so: `select 
    name,
    addr,
    coalesce(salary, max(salary) over(partition by name)) new_salary from c`

Comment: quick question, when I changed the data type of salary to char(10), I am not getting the needed value while when I put datatype as money I got value. Is there any way I can get value after changing salary datatype to char(20)